# saveSnapshot does not work after modifying the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ckeditor

I have a web site with inline CKEditors, on which I modify the HTML DOM with javascript and then try to fire the saveSnapshot event to save the modifications to the server. And here's the tricky part; if I make only one DOM change (remove an element) and call `editor.fire("saveSnapshot");` it seems to work fine, but if I remove more than one element from the DOM I very often get the error below.

I have tried many different variations on doing what I need to do but with no success, except fire the event `editor.fire("change")` instead (which seems to be not recommended for some reason by CK). I have tried to delay with timeouts if things are happening to fast for the CK, using different combinations of lock/unlock snapshot events etc.

So, my questions are:

1) what is the reason using `fire("change)` is not recommended?

2) why is this behaviour causing CK to err?

Any clue that can take me forward on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Error message from CK:

```
ckeditor.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
at a (ckeditor.js:149)
at CKEDITOR.dom.range.createBookmark2 (ckeditor.js:151)
at Array.createBookmarks2 (ckeditor.js:510)
at CKEDITOR.dom.selection.createBookmarks2 (ckeditor.js:463)
at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.Image (ckeditor.js:1072)
at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.UndoManager.save (ckeditor.js:1067)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:1063)
at a.n (ckeditor.js:10)
at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
```

Here's the code where I modify the DOM (remove one or several elements) and fire the saveSnapshot event for each affected editor instance:

```
    var sectionIds = [];

    if (textMarkers instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < textMarkers.length; i++) {
            var textMarker = textMarkers[i];
            $("#sectionText-" + textMarker.sectionId).find("span.hypo-marker[data-marker-id='" + textMarker.id + "']").remove();
            if (sectionIds.indexOf(textMarker.sectionId) === -1) {
                sectionIds.push(textMarker.sectionId);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $("#sectionText-" + textMarkers.sectionId).find("span.hypo-marker[data-marker-id='" + textMarkers.id + "']").remove();
        sectionIds.push(textMarkers.sectionId);
    }

    // Trigger save event on editor for each section that's been updated
    for (var c = 0; c < sectionIds.length; c++) {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances["sectionText-" + sectionIds[c]];
        // editor.fire("saveSnapshot");
        editor.fire("change");
    }
```

I use CKEditor standard 4.7 with Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) with the following CKEditor config:

```
var options = {
    removePlugins: 'magicline,horizontalrule',
    skin: 'office2013',
    extraPlugins: 'colorbutton,panelbutton,panel,floatpanel,button,scayt,html5audio,uploadwidget,youtube,image2,uploadimage,keystrokes,notification,notificationaggregator,magicline2,undo',
    language: 'sv',
    title: false,
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false,
    extraAllowedContent: 'span(*)[*]; img(*)[!src,*]; div(*)[*]; a(*)[*]; p(*)[*]; i(*); table(*)[*]; thead(*)[*]; tbody(*)[*]; tr(*)[*]; td(*)[*];',
    // disallowedContent: 'span(rangySelectionBoundary)[id];',
    imageUploadUrl: '/api/v2/editor/images',
    //filebrowserUploadUrl: '/api/v2/editor/images',
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' }
    ],
    removeButtons: "Anchor",
    magicline_color: "#00a651",
    coreStyles_italic: { element: 'i', overrides: 'em' }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your first question:

It is not recommended to catch every `change` event because it gets fired quite often and it may prove quite heavy however firing should not be a problem.

If you intend to catch it maybe you could add extra data to that event based on which you can identify yours - https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.event-method-fire.

The change event also doesn't get fired in source mode so if you use that mode, you need to find some other way of checking for code changes (maybe periodically comparing previous and current `textarea` value).

Comment: I already handle the fact that the change event is fired very often. Since I have only inline editors the issue with source mode is not a problem. Still would like to know why the saveSnapshot event doesn't work...